# School assignment, i dont know what im doing wrong

Tags: javascript, loops

can someone help me with this code for school, i just dont dont know what im doing wrong..

keep in mind..
Getal means: Number, and is already adjusted to all of the number of * in the console.
Resultaat means result.
Opdracht means Assignment

Here is my code,
Btw you can look at the test script, those answers is what it needs to be.
im only available to use, for loop, if statement, and a variable for the * it self aside from resultaat..

```
<script>
function opdracht(getal){

    let resultaat = "*";

    for (let i = 0; i < getal; i++){
        resultaat += i + " "
    }

    return resultaat;
}

// Test script
test([-1], "*", opdracht);
test([0], "*", opdracht);
test([1], "*", opdracht);
test([2], "* **", opdracht);
test([10], "* ** *** **** ***** ****** ******* ******** ********* **********", opdracht);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please include the image of the console, as stated. I'm pretty sure I know what it shows, but we can't help until you show us what the problem actually is, as well as state a real question, like iota said.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the goal is to print a series of stars, increasing the number of stars until you reach the argument. Right now I'd guess you're getting "*0 1 2 ...". Without writing the whole answer out for you, I'd like to direct you to the [string repeat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). `"*".repeat(3)` will get you `"***"`. Use that inside the loop.

Comment: Being a school assignment, I think they might be expecting a solution using nested loops

Answer (score 0):

You need two nested loops; the first/outer one will add spaces ( ) between numbers and the second/inner one will print as many stars (`*`) as the current number you are considering.

Furthermore you have to take into account the fact that if the argument is < 2, you have to print just one star.

```js
function opdracht(getal) {
  // you initialize the result
  let resultaat = '*'

  // if the number is greater than 1...
  if (getal > 1) {
    // ... for each number btween 2 and the passed argument... 
    for (let i = 2; i <= getal; i++) {
      // ... you add a space to the result and...
      resultaat += ' ';
      for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        // ... add as many stars as the current number is
        resultaat += '*'
      }
    }
  }

  // finally you print the result
  console.log(resultaat);
}

//tests
opdracht(-1);
opdracht(0);
opdracht(1);
opdracht(2);
opdracht(10);
```

#### The loops step by step

Consider the case `opdracht(3)`:

- you enter the outer loop:

  - `resultaat` is `*`
  - `i` is `2`
  - `resultaat` becomes `*`
  - you enter the inner loop

    - `j` is `0`
    - `resultaat` becomes `* *`
    - `j` becomes `1`
    - `resultaat` becomes `* **`
    - `j` becomes `2` and you exit the inner loop
  - `i` becomes `3`
  - `resultaat` becomes `* **`
  - you enter the inner loop

    - `j` is `0`
    - `resultaat` becomes `* ** *`
    - `j` becomes `1`
    - `resultaat` becomes `* ** **`
    - `j` becomes `2`
    - `resultaat` becomes `* ** ***`
    - `j` becomes `3` and you exit the inner loop
  - `i` becomes `4` and you exit the outer loop

Answer (score -1):

you use three arguments to function , though you havent defined them in function , read the documentation about js , this is very good resource to study js https://javascript.info/